# Get WordPress installation working with nginx in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

Basically I have a site, called example.com. Within this site, there is a WordPress-Blog, wich should be accessible under "example.com/blog/". The actual directory where the blog is installed is not "/blog/", but "/blog/de/", as this project has multiple stand-alone-blogs for different languages.

The problem is, that WordPress cannot access to wp-content and wp-include files, because WordPress tries to load css (and other) files via example.com/blog/wp-content/....

So i want to get my Blog running under "example.com/blog", but all WordPress-Files should be loaded from /blog/de/.

This is my nginx-vhost-config for /blog-Location:

```
 location /blog {

    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /de/index.php?$args;
    rewrite ^(/wp-content/.*)$ /de/wp-content/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*)+$ /blog/de/index.php?$1;
}
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
```

I am totally new to nginx, so every possible solution is welcome!

Comment: You say that there are multiple stand-alone-blogs for different languages - are these other blogs hosted under `example.com/blog/`?

Comment: for each blog, there is a directory in the /blog/ direcory. e.g.:
/blog/de
/blog/en/
/blog/es/
and so on

The Blogs should be always available under domain.tld/blog. We do have different domains for each site like example.de, example.com, pointing to the same source code

Comment: Are you saying that the URL `example.cc/blog` points to physical `path/to/blog/cc/`? And that any individual domain is only expected to support one language?

Comment: exactly, yes. Each language runs on an own domain. The domain root points always to the same directory, but the blogs are installed in own directories for each language. Just like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to alias the location `/blog` to the path `/blog/de`. The complication is the way in which PHP files are handled, particularly when other applications are hosted within the same domain.

First internally rewrite `/blog` to `/blog/de`:

```
location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*)$ /blog/de$1 last;
}
```

Then implement the `/blog/de` location with a nested location to handle PHP:

```
set $wordpress /blog/de/index.php;

location ^~ /blog/de {
    # root inherited from server container???
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $wordpress;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $wordpress;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass    ...;
    }
}
```

I make `/blog/de` a priority prefix location, to avoid a conflict with any other php location. But that would not be necessary if this is the only application within this server block.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried your code, it returns a 502 Bad Gateway. Don't you think its possible to make the URL always /blog and not /blog/de?

Comment: The rewrite is internal so the URL *is* always /blog. The 502 is a problem with fastcgi_pass, which I left for you to fill in the blanks.